# The Jacobian of the map $f(x) = |x|^{p-2}x$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $ f : \mathbb R^N \longrightarrow \mathbb R^N  $ defined by

$$f(x) = |x|^{p-2}x$$

for all $ x \in \mathbb R^N $ with $p >1 $. Where $|x|$ is the euclidean norm in $ \mathbb R^N $.

I need to calculate the jacobian $J f(a)$ in any fixed point  $ a \in \mathbb R^N $.

By definition we need to show that there is a linear transformation $ T_{a}: \mathbb R^N \longrightarrow \mathbb R^N $ such that

$$f(a + h) := f(a) + T_{a}(h) + r(h)$$

where $ \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{r(h)}{|h|} = 0 $.

Anyone have any ideas that can help me?

Comment: [Earlier today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729497/its-true-that-lim-t-to-0-fracx-0-tp-2-x-0p-2t-0/2729516#2729516) you were given examples that your first limit doesn't exit when $n=1$. Your second limit only exists when $a=0$. And, by the way, your candidate for the derivative is wrong when $n=1$: why would you think that it would be that for any $n$?

Comment: If this limit there exists then it is the transformation that I need. But I have no idea how to find another linear transformation that works

Comment: For the third time today: **the limit you want, when it exists, is not zero**. And the derivative is not what you propose, even in the easy one-variable-calculus case $n=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. What is the gradient of this map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your intuition is wrong (and I really cannot imagine where you got that "intuition": in the case where $n=1$ and $x>0$, you know that $T_ah=(p-1)a^{p-2}h$). For $n>1$, it would be very unusual that $T_a$ is a scalar multiple of the identity, as you propose.

For $a\ne0$, the function $f$ is differentiable since $|x|$, exponentials, and products are differentiable.

For $a\ne0$: It is well known that the entries of $T_a$ in the canonical basis are 
$$
(T_a)_{kj}=\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_j}(a).
$$
As $f_k(x)=|x|^{p-2}x_k=(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)^{p/2-1}x_k$, 
\begin{align}
(T_a)_{kj}&=\left.2(p/2-1)(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)^{p/2-2}x_k^2+(x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2)^{p/2-1}\right|_{x=a}\\ \ \\
&=|a|^{p-2}\,\left[(p-2)(a_1^2+\cdots+a_n^2)^{-1}a_k^2+1 \right].
\end{align}

Now for $a=0$.

For $p<2$: a necessary condition for differentiability at a point is that the partial derivatives exist at such point. We have, for $j\ne k$,
$$
\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_j}(0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f_k(te_j)-f_k(0)}{t}
=\lim_{t\to0}\frac0t=0;
$$
for $j=k$, 
$$
\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x_k}(0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f_k(te_k)-f_k(0)}{t}
=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^{p-1}}t=\lim_{t\to0}t^{p-2},
$$
which doesn't exist. So $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

For $p=2$, you have $f(x)=x$, which is obviously differentiable everywhere and $T_a=I$ for all $a$.

For $p>2$, the computations above show that $\partial f_k/\partial x_j(0)=0$. And one can check that $\lim_{a\to0}(T_a))_{kj}=0$, so the partial derivatives are continuous and so $f$ is differentiable at zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: Glad I could help. You may want to check the computations carefully, as I'm prone to make mistakes.